# Summarizing table columns in a dynamic text expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, dynamic-text, arcade

I have some data in a table that I would like to perform some statistics and have that placed in a text box on my map Layout. While I could do this by hand, I'd like to do it dynamically so when I update the data later on I don't have to edit my text boxes.

My data looks something like this:

```
| County | POP2019 | Deaths |
|--------|---------|--------|
| Benton | 1000    | 2      |
| King   | 100     | 1      |
```

I want to do a statewide death rate calculation like this

```
((Sum of Deaths / Sum of Population) * 100) Round to 5 decimals

Round(((Sum($feature.Deaths) / Sum($feature.POP2019)) * 100), 5)
```

But that dynamic text expression doesn't sum up the column! It prints out each and every row, and does not sum them up.

[image: Expression Results]

Comment: What table are you summarising and what shape are you labeling?

Comment: If your data is in a database (enterprise or file geodatabase) I would create a database view to do this.  If you want the results to be dynamic, there are not a lot of other options.

Comment: The file is in a Geodatabase feature class, and is part of the dataset currently being displayed on the map. It'm trying to create a text box on my Map Layout with dynamic text. I've already created a few out dynamic text boxes that contain SUMs and MEANs of other columns for other purposes, but I'm having trouble with this formula here.